# Laravel 5.2 - PHP method require does not work

Tags: php, laravel

I am not used to making code in Laravel, but I need to solve this problem that seems to be relatively simple. I'm trying to call the database in my .blade file to foreach a table, but I don't know how to do that.

```
<?php 
   $pdo = require('pdo/conexao.php');
?>
```

I used this standard PHP system, but every time I do it this way, I get the error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." How do I call a database through laravel?

Comment: are you using compatible php version for Laravel 5.2

Comment: "_I'm trying to call the database in my .blade file_" That should be done in a model or controller, not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Adding DB calls in the view is `not recommended`.

If you are using Laravel so here is a [full doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) of how to pass data to view.

You need to use Model or Raw Query to get the data and then pass that data to your view.

Comment: Ok. I created the function in Modal, now, how do I call it in the view?

Comment: I use this way "{{ App\models\Ticket::getUsers }}" but does not work :(

Comment: Are you using Controller If yes can you share the code of controller?

Comment: {{ \App\Models\Ticket::all() }} and on that you can apply loop etc to render accordingly.